# shorten java syntax and writing performance

Tags: java, performance, syntax, upgrade

This is my main method:

```
gosub(module_1, "Hello world!");
```

is there an available syntax allowing me to simply use:

```
~module_1("Hello world!");
```

i do remember seeing something like that in another project i reviewed,

is there any other simpler syntax?

Comment: I'm betting that other project was not Java.

Comment: it was a slightly modified version, i am accepting any shortcuts that java can offer as well

Comment: Java doesn't really offer any shortcuts of this form.

Comment: perhaps some plugin? For example groovy, or something like using lambda

Comment: If you want something with a different syntax, it won't be Java.  Maybe someone has written a preprocessor or something that converts code with special syntax to Java, but I don't know of any personally.